# Need to know if i can use jmeter for doing load \performance testing for voice first react native apps

Tags: java, https, jmeter

I tried to perform a load test on a react native voice first mobile app using JMeter https script recorder.

I can test login\signup, but when the app speaks, I get the following error message as a response data from JMeter :

> Remote host closed connection during handshake ensure browser is set
>   to accept the jMeter proxy certificate

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all steps described here:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

Frequent errors are:

- Not adding JMeter CA Certificate in browser if using FF or system if using Chrome or Edge
- Not adding it as a Certificate Authority server
- Not checking "Accept this certificate to for web applications"
- Not checking "Use this proxy for all protocols" in browser

More complex to diagnose and fix:

- Having a version of Java that does not have the same algorithms as the target server. You'll have to debug and change java.security content to accept an algorithm accepted by the server

Comment: Hi,
I followed all the steps mentioned in the above link. The app i am trying to test is a mobile application.I downloaded the Jmeter certificate to my ios mobile and trusted it .Right now the issue i am facing is , since the app i am testing is a mobile voice app. Jmeter is not able to pick up voice.So i am wondering does jmeter support load testing for apps that run by voice at all?
Can you please help

Comment: If you're getting the error you mention , then you missed some steps. JMeter is able to capture http(s) traffic , if the application communicates using this protocol then JMeter is able to capture it. What version of JMeter are you using ?

Comment: Is it on Android or IOS ?

Comment: Hi,
I am using v 4.1 and its ios

Comment: Also can you show what you have in View Results Tree located under Test Script Recorder , please show the 3 tabs

Comment: sampler result:
Thread Name: 
Sample Start: 1969-12-31 19:00:00 EST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 875
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 875
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 
Response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

Response headers:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

REQUEST (TAB 2)
CONNECT gateway.watsonplatform.net:443 HTTP/1.1
RESPONSE DATA:
java net ssl excep